# Utilizing resources of separate apps on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript, sandbox

**Is it possible to write software on the mac that will launch other separate applications, tell them what to do, etc etc**? What language would best suite doing this? (Assuming it's Mac specific).

I'm fairly new to Mac programming, though I have a strong background in iOS. I've seen multiple companies in the past write a script that will cross-compile source code, basically you run your app from the Terminal and it floats around your OS, grabbing what it needs to compile and spits out an Xcode, Eclipse and Unity-ready versions of your source code. I'm familiar with iOS, and how it crashes the second you try to use another apps resources. That is what leads me to the original question:

Is it possible to write software on the mac that will launch other separate applications, tell them what to do, etc etc? Specifically tasks like launch Safari, take a screenshot, launch disk utility, launch mail, email screenshot. I know that OS X allows you to play around a bit more than iOS, but the question is how much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still rather up to what each app will *let* you do, rather than just being able to do anything, but take a look at OS X's scripting/automation abilities. Primarily this is accessed through [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html), but there's now a [JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html) frontend as well (new to Yosemite).

If you're looking at building a native application that takes advantage of other applications, the same scripting abilities can also be reached via the [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) from Cocoa (Objective-C/Swift).

Comment: Thank you very much for the info, incredibly helpful! So if I want to write a Utility app that utilizes other aspects of apps, I could most likely build it in Xcode and utilize Scripting Bridge from Cocoa, and check out Apple Script to see what I may access, right?

Comment: Yup! The application Script Editor (in `/Applications/Utilities`) has a Library window that lets you browse the commands that applications expose, and you can use it to write simple (Apple or Java) scripts in the app to test that what you want to do is even possible.

Comment: But be aware that sending Apple Events to other processes from a sandboxed applications requires [specific entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html), which will only be approved for the App Store on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @duskwuff Interesting, thank you. Would one need these entitlements if they just plan on using it as an in-house app?

Comment: If it's in-house, you don't need to sandbox it. (You *can* if you really want, but it's not necessary.) Entitlements are only necessary for sandboxed apps.